# What is wrong with my conversion from local time to UTC

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytz

According to timeanddate.com, currently Chicago is 5 hours behind UTC. However, my Python app thinks differently:

```
import datetime
import pytz

    local_tz = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')
    local_time = datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 6, 0, 0, tzinfo=local_tz)
    utc_time = local_time.astimezone(pytz.utc)
    print(local_time)
    print(utc_time)

2015-08-06 00:00:00-05:51
2015-08-06 05:51:00+00:00
```

I am getting the same results with both 'America/Chicago' and 'US/Central'. Why is the offset -05:51 instead of -05:00?

Comment: I'm not sure where the :51 comes from, but Chicago is currently on CDT, not CST.  CST is -6:00.

Comment: What version of pytz are you using? (you can check with import pytz, pytz.VERSION)

Comment: @Bacon my version is 2015.4.

Comment: @AShelly time zones change over the years, and I believe that by default `pytz` returns the *earliest* historical time zone rule for the location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pytz` timezone objects need to be initialized with a specific time before they're used, and creating a `datetime` with a `tzinfo=` parameter does not allow for that. You have to use the `localize` method of the `pytz` object to add the timezone to the `datetime`.

```
>>> local_tz = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')
>>> local_time = local_tz.localize(datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 6, 0, 0))
>>> print local_time
2015-08-06 00:00:00-05:00
>>> utc_time = local_time.astimezone(pytz.utc)
>>> print utc_time
2015-08-06 05:00:00+00:00
```

Comment: Yes it worked with localize. However, this tzinfo= thing is very confusing! It allows for subtle bugs like this one. What do we need the tzinfo parameter in datetime.datetime constructor for?

Comment: @AlexC I believe the authors of the `datetime` class intended for the `tzinfo` to work differently - it is supposed to deliver a different offset based on the `datetime` that is passed into its methods. This has a fatal flaw in that it can't handle the overlap at the end of DST when the same hour occurs twice. There are other `tzinfo` implementations such as `dateutil` that work as expected, except of course for the unavoidable flaw.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I think the only case when it is safe to use tzinfo= is this: tzinfo=pytz.utc. Is that correct?

Comment: @AlexC correct, `utc` is safe because it is unchanging - it doesn't have a history, and it doesn't support DST.

Comment: @AlexC: any timezone with a fixed utc offset will do. Use `localize(naive, is_dst=None)` to assert that `naive` datetime object represent a unique valid local time.